# How do you find the derivative using the power rule for numbers to the 1/2?

Tags: calculus

To find the derivative for f(x) = 63^1/2 * 65^1/2 , how would you use the power rule? The fraction is confusing me.

Comment: The function given is a constant, so it's derivative is $0$. In general, $ \frac{d}{dx} x^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2} x^{(1/2) - 1} = \frac{1}{2} x^{-1/2}$, by the standard formula.

Comment: Since there is no $x$ on the right-hand side, of course the derivative is zero.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense! Thank you